# Menu using jQuery accordion: make header's links work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, callback, accordion

I am trying to use Jquery UI accordion module to create a sidebar containing categories of objects (headers) that when clicked display the sub-categories (contents).

The accordion itselfs works fine: when I click on a category, it displays a new section containing the links towards the different sub-categories' pages BUT the links towards the main categories do not work anymore. I would like a click on a category to do TWO things: change the accordion appropriately AND open the link.

I have searched the web for 2 hours, and the only clue I found was to use a callback to the change event of the accordion, but I am extremely newbie in jQuery/Javascript, so I don't know how to do this or if it's the best option.

If I use "mouseover" to trigger the accordion, then everything works fine: the click event on a category is still opening the category page. Should I use mouseover or is there a solution using click as the event ? (the problem is that jquery generates a client-side event, whereas the link should generate a server-side event)

You can check what I mean live [here](http://young-leaf-5066.heroku.com/) (clicking on the "Media" in the left sidebar should open the sub-categories but also open the list of objects within the Media categories, whereas clicking on sub-menu "books" works fine).

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using links in the accordion headers, use the accordion's change event.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    changestart: function (event, ui) {
        var href = ui.newHeader.attr( "href" );
        // do something with href
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin ! ... You showed me the way ... In my case, however, to make it work, I had to change a bit your answer : remove the ".find("a")" part and use the CHANGESTART event instead of the CHANGE event, if I want to be able to open href in the same window. Thanks a lot !

Comment: and maybe you could also replace the "change" by "changestart" in the piece of code, so other readers will directly get it right ? Regards, citraL

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-navigation

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ navigation: true });
```

Comment: Thanks Khaled, but I tried this without success, although I don't know why, but it does not work.

Comment: maybe it's for external link not for header